# autoconf check bfd library from binutils

Tags: gnu, autoconf, binutils

on linux, autoconf 2.65, binutils 2.20.0. I need to do something like this:

```
AC_CHECK_HEADER([bfd.h],
                  [AC_DEFINE([HAVE_BFD_H])],
                  [AC_MSG_WARN([Header "bfd.h" from the binutils not found!])],
   [[#ifdef HAVE_BFD_H
     #include <bfd.h>
     #endif]]
   )
    AC_SEARCH_LIBS([bfd_openr],  [bfd],
                 [AC_MSG_RESULT([OK, found libbfd])],
[AC_MSG_ERROR([BFD library from the binutils package not found!])])
```

The second check failed, probably due to dependence to -lintl.

Can anybody here show me how to correct it? Thanks a lot!

Crack

Answer (score 1):

The 5th argument to AC_SEARCH_LIBS is a list of libraries to use.  Try:

```
AC_SEARCH_LIBS([bfd_openr], [bfd], [], [], [-lintl])
```

(I left the 3rd and 4th arguments empty for clarity, not as
a recommendation to change.)

Comment: I have tried the 5th argument but the check still failed. I am not sure if intl is linked correctly here. When I did
 
`AC_CHECK_LIB(intl, main, LIBS="-lintl $LIBS")`

intl was not found. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Jus If intl is not found, you need to set LDFLAGS.  (eg, ./configure LDFLAGS=-L/path/to/lib, where /path/to/lib/lintl.so is the library against which you wish to link.)